# Manipulating Bibtex reference fields

Tags: bibtex

I need to use a specific format for my reference lists for my publications, however, I don't really understand how I can manipulated BibTeX to do what I want. I am trying to get the following format:

> X.Y. Author1, A. B. Author2, *Journal (with abbreviations)*, **Volume
>   Number** (Issue Number), First Page (year).
>
> or for 3+ Authors
>
> X.Y. Author1, A. B. Author2, *Journal (with abbreviations)*, **Volume
>   Number** (Issue Number), First Page (year).

I tried reading through the documentation but it gets a little complicated and I am pretty new at this...

If anyone can give me some help, that would be great.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Could you set up a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to help the people here answering your question? The [`makebst`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib) utility may be useful for you.

Comment: With no MWE, this is too localized.